# Preimage of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given that $f:E \rightarrow F$ is a vector space homomorfism  and $W \subset F$ a subspace, I want to prove $$W \cap \mathrm{im}(f)=\{0\} \implies f^{-1}[W]=\ker(f)\ ,$$ where $f^{-1}[W]$ is the preimage of $W$.

What I'm trying is:
\begin{align*}
\ker(f) &=f^{-1}[\{0\}] \\ &=f^{-1}[W \cap \mathrm{im}(f)] \\ &=f^{-1}[W] \cap f^{-1}[\mathrm{im}(f)] \\ &=f^{-1}[W] \cap E \\ &=f^{-1}[W]\ .
\end{align*}

My simple question is: is that correct?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $$f^{-1}[W \cap \mathrm{im}(f)] = f^{-1}[W] \cap f^{-1}[\mathrm{im}(f)]$$ is true in general?

Comment: I would proceed like this:

$\subseteq$ :

Given $u \in f^{-1}(W \cap Im(f))$, then $f(u) \in W \cap Im(f)$, then $u \in f^{-1}(W) \cap f^-{1}(Im(f))$.

$\supseteq$

Given $u \in f^{-1}(W) \cap f^{-1}(Im(f))$, then $f(u) \in W \cap Im(f)$, then $u \in f^{-1}(W \cap (Im(f))$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have no other objections.

Comment: Your proof is totally fine. Here's another one, which is possibly a little more conceptually satisfying. $x$ is in $f^{-1}[W]$ if and only if $f(x)\in W$; while $x$ is in ker$(f)$ if and only if $f(x)=0$. Can you prove that these are equivalent under the hypothesis $W\cap{}$im$(f)=\{0\}$?

Comment: @MusséRedi It's true in general that the inverse image preserves unions, intersections and (relative) complements.

Comment: @egreg It seems plausible, although I do not quite believe it until I have worked it out a bit, by myself. For some reason I am sceptic about the identity.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is correct. A different approach is noting that the equality
$$
f^{-1}[W]=f^{-1}[W\cap\operatorname{im}(f)]
$$
holds for every *subset* of $F$.